# What's the right pattern to reduce the number of rows within one table in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

By *reducing* I mean some form of caching when you can reduce 100 rows with 1 row (accumulate counters etc).

I want to able to answer queries how many people are from %EACH_COUNTRY, so basically return an array of pairs / map from `(Country, COUNT)`. And then I've got huge number (think of `50 * 10^8`) of people so I can't allocate 1 row for each person, so I'd like to `cache` the results somehow to keep `PeopleTable` under `10^6` entries at least (and then merge the results with the fast read from `CacheTable`). By caching I mean count the number of people with `country=%SPECIFIC_COUNTRY`, write `%SPECIFIC_COUNTRY, COUNT(*)` in `CacheTable` (to be precise, increment the count for `%SPECIFIC_COUNTRY` and then remove these rows from `PeopleTable`):

```
personId,           country
1132312312,         Russia
2344333333,         the USA
1344111112,         France
1133555555,         Russia
1132666666,         Russia
3334124124,         Russia

....
```

and then
`CacheTable`

```
country,        count
Russia,         4
France,         1
```

Comment: This really depends on your data model - what data you have & what do you want to achieve.  Your question is too broad now, please add details

Comment: @AlexOtt Added details

Comment: How precise it should be? Really precise, or "approximate"?

Comment: Well, it'll really nice if I can make it really precise. You probably can give me an idea of multiple solutions if possible and then every SO user will be able to choose what suits him the most.

Comment: @AlexOtt answered the question.